# How do I use Head and Tail to print specific lines of a file

Tags: shell, unix, arguments, tail, unix-head

I want to say output lines 5 - 10 of a file, as arguments passed in.

How could I use `head` and `tail` to do this?

where `firstline = $2` and `lastline = $3` and `filename = $1`.

Running it should look like this:

```
./lines.sh filename firstline lastline
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aside from the answers given by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747990/1430833) and [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747983/1430833), you can also use a single `sed` command:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=$1
firstline=$2
lastline=$3

# Basics of sed:
#   1. sed commands have a matching part and a command part.
#   2. The matching part matches lines, generally by number or regular expression.
#   3. The command part executes a command on that line, possibly changing its text.
#
# By default, sed will print everything in its buffer to standard output.  
# The -n option turns this off, so it only prints what you tell it to.
#
# The -e option gives sed a command or set of commands (separated by semicolons).
# Below, we use two commands:
#
# ${firstline},${lastline}p
#   This matches lines firstline to lastline, inclusive
#   The command 'p' tells sed to print the line to standard output
#
# ${lastline}q
#   This matches line ${lastline}.  It tells sed to quit.  This command 
#   is run after the print command, so sed quits after printing the last line.
#   
sed -ne "${firstline},${lastline}p;${lastline}q" < ${filename}
```

Or, to avoid any external utilites, if you're using a recent version of bash (or zsh):

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=$1
firstline=$2
lastline=$3

i=0
exec <${filename}  # redirect file into our stdin
while read ; do    # read each line into REPLY variable
  i=$(( $i + 1 ))  # maintain line count

  if [ "$i" -ge "${firstline}" ] ; then
    if [ "$i" -gt "${lastline}" ] ; then
      break
    else
      echo "${REPLY}"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: @user2232423 All Unix commands have a standard input (stdin) and a standard output (stdout). The commands `sed`, `awk`, and many others (including `head` and `tail`) read their input from stdin, process it, and write the results to stdout. By default, stdin/stdout are attached to the terminal. Using redirection (eg: `COMMAND < FILE1 > FILE2`), you can set stdin for `COMMAND` to read from `FILE1` and stdout to write to `FILE2`. This is fundamental to Unix; you might want to check out a tutorial  (http://www.ceri.memphis.edu/computer/docs/unix/bshell.htm) or a book to get a better understanding.

Comment: @user2232423 Also, both `awk` and `sed` offer a great deal of power for text processing.  If you're going to spend much time in Unix, these two commands (plus `grep`) will be very, very useful.  They're worth learning, although they're easier to learn in little bits at a time. You might find [sed & awk](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do) to be a useful book.

Comment: Thanks, great advice. I have a few things I am unsure of, like how does sed match lines with the code as simple as ${firstline},${lastline}p << what is actually going on there?

Comment: @user2232423 The `${firstline},${lastline}` match only applies to `p` (the print command); `${lastline}q` will only match `${lastline}`, so we only quit after the last line.

Comment: @user2232423 You should really read a tutorial on the Unix shell.  You're conflating two distinct concepts (arguments and redirection).  The `<${filename}` tells the shell to connect the file whose name is in the shell variable `filename` to the stdin of the `sed` process.  `sed` receives its *arguments* on the command line (`-e` and `"${firstline},${lastline}p;${lastline}q"` are arguments).  These arguments tell `sed` how to process what it reads from stdin, and what to write to stdout.

Answer (score 42):

```
head -n XX # <-- print first XX lines
tail -n YY # <-- print last YY lines
```

If you want lines from 20 to 30 that means you want 11 lines starting from 20 and finishing at 30:

```
head -n 30 file | tail -n 11
# 
# first 30 lines
#                 last 11 lines from those previous 30
```

That is, you firstly get first `30` lines and then you select the last `11` (that is, `30-20+1`).

So in your code it would be:

```
head -n $3 $1 | tail -n $(( $3-$2 + 1 ))
```

Based on `firstline = $2`, `lastline = $3`, `filename = $1`

```
head -n $lastline $filename | tail -n $(( $lastline -$firstline + 1 ))
```

Comment: could use `tail -n +$2` instead

Comment: @AurélienOoms not sure what you exactly mean here. In which case do you mean to use this? After `head`, I assume.

Comment: I meant `head -n $3 $1 | tail -n +$2`.

Comment: Combining your answer with @dado's.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' You can also use like this
     `tail -n +${firstline} $filename | head -n $(($lastline -$firstline + 1))`

Answer (score 8):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -vs="$begin" -ve="$end" 'NR>=s&&NR<=e' "$f"
```

in above line:

```
$begin is your $2
$end is your $3
$f is your $1
```

Comment: I prefer keeping it simple by using head and tail,

Comment: @user2232423 ok, you are free to choose the solution most suits you. we have different definition of "simple". **a)** you need two processes with head and tail. awk is only one process.  **b)** awk could also quit processing after reaching your `$3` ( I didn't do it in my answer), if you have a monster file. **c)** awk could validating your `$2 $3` e.g if `$2>$3` then doesn't process the file at all. you have to write extra script for your head/tail. awk is simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, could you breakdown your one-liner and explain it?

Comment: `-vs="$begin"` sets the awk-internal variable `s` to the value stored in the shell variable `$begin`. Same goes for `-ve`. The main part (the awk script) is the `'NR>=s&&NR<=e'`, which just means print the line if the line number is between s and e. `'NR==5'` for example would just print line 5. You could also use the shell variables directly, but in that case can't use '  ' since the shell would not expand `$foo` inside single quotes: `awk "NR>=$begin&&NR<=$end" filename` But you could get in trouble with \-escaping stuff in scripts.

Comment: @JustinSane it works, (expand shell var in awk codes) but is not good practice. what if the `$begin` var need to be used 30 times? and  what if later the var-name was changed into `$start`? also the special char cases..

Answer (score 5):

Save this as "**script.sh**":

```
#!/bin/sh

filename="$1"
firstline=$2
lastline=$3
linestoprint=$(($lastline-$firstline+1))

tail -n +$firstline "$filename" | head -n $linestoprint
```

There is *NO ERROR HANDLING* (for simplicity) so you have to call your script as following:

**./script.sh yourfile.txt firstline lastline**

```
$ ./script.sh yourfile.txt 5 10
```

If you need only line "10" from yourfile.txt:

```
$ ./script.sh yourfile.txt 10 10
```

Please make sure that:
(firstline > 0) AND (lastline  > 0) AND (firstline <= lastline)

Comment: the `+` in `tail -n +$firstline` is the key.