# Extract line from a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a text file of 5000000 lines and I want to extract one line from each 1000 and write them into a new text file. The new text file should be of 5000 line.

Can you help me?

Comment: Which shell? What have you tried?

Comment: Which line, the first one or the last one?

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use either `head` or `tail`, depends which line you'd like to extract.

To extract first line from each file (for instance `*.txt` files):

```
head -n1 *.txt | grep -ve ^= -e ^$ > first.txt
```

To extract the last line from each file, simply use `tail` instead of `head`.

For extracting specific line, see: [How do I use Head and Tail to print specific lines of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15747912/55075).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a python script to do so. However, the same logic can be used with your shell as well. Here is the python code.

```
input_file = 'path/file.txt'
output_file = 'path/output.txt'
n = 0

with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    with ope(output_file, 'w') as o:
        for line in f:
            n += 1
            if n == 1000:
                o.write(line)
                n = 0
```

Basically, you initialise a counter then you iterate over the file line by line, you increment the counter for each line, if the counter hits 1000 you write the line in the new file and reset the counter back.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash) is how to iterate over lines of a file using Bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk 'NR%1000==1' infile > outfile
```

see this link for more options: [remove odd or even lines from text file in terminal in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309020/remove-odd-or-even-lines-from-text-file-in-terminal-in-linux)